# Nested if statement returns nothing in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Here is my list (of lists):

```
mylist = [ [1, "John", None, "Doe"], [2, "Jane", "group1", "Zee"], [3, "Lex", "group2", "Fee"]]

y = 2

for sublist in mylist:
    if sublist[0] == y:   # meaning the third list
        if sublist[2] == None:
            print(sublist[2]) # this should print nothing
        else:
            print(sublist[2]) #this should print something
```

The end result is that nothing prints for this code.

I am trying to do a check for situations where I have a `None` value in my list (of lists). This method above doesn't seem to work.

I cannot figure out why it refuses to print anything at all, but I assume the nested `if sublist[2] == None:` may have something to do with it.

Comment: This prints "group1" on my machine. Using python 3.4.

Comment: `sublist[0] == y`, since `y = 2`, will be true for the *second* list.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, your code prints `group1`

Comment: If you print the same thing (`sublist[2]`), regardless of the value of `sublist[2]`, why do you have the inner `if` at all?

Comment: If I assigned y=1 then its print None..What you actually want?

Comment: @ScottHunter this is just an example scenario. I was attempting to make a working/running example

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to do a check for situations where I have a None value in my list (of lists)

Then just check for membership with `in` for every sub list:

```
for sublist in mylist:
    if None in sublist:
        # do your check
        print("None in list: ", sublist)
```

prints:

```
None in list:  [1, 'John', None, 'Doe']
```

If you want to just see if a `None` exists in general just use `any`:

```
any(None in sub for sub in mylist)
```

which returns `True` since `None` is in `mylist[0]`

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish.
You like to enumerate through a list of lists, then check the `y`-th field to see if it contains `None`.

The problem you are facing is that when you do:

```
y = 2
```

indicating the third field and later you do:

```
if sublist[0] == y:
```

then you are checking if the **first** field (indicated by `[0]`) of the `sublist` is equal to `2`

which brings you to the third sublist, not the third field in the sublist enumeration. This is where your code goes wrong.

You need to drop the `if sublist[0] == y:` completely, and simply check `sublist[y]`

The following code will enumerate your list of lists, then check the `y`-th field for `None`:

```
mylist = [ [1, "John", None, "Doe"], [2, "Jane", "group1", "Zee"], [3, "Lex", "group2", "Fee"]]

y = 2

for sublist in mylist:
    if sublist[y] == None:
        print(sublist[y]) # this should print nothing
    else:
        print(sublist[y]) #this should print something
```

If you want to check *any* field containing `None`, you get something like this:

```
mylist = [ [1, "John", None, "Doe"], [2, "Jane", "group1", "Zee"], [3, "Lex", "group2", "Fee"]]

for sublist in mylist:
    for field in sublist:
        if field == None:
            print("None detected in: " + str(sublist))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and detailed explanation. I would give you an upvote, but somebody gave me a downvote and my reputation is below 15 again.

Comment: @coolpy Thanks for the feed back, good luck. You can always try to "mark as answer" :-)